# Inability to access django models or postgres tables on heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

This morning in my dbshell, I tried to wipe my database with:

```
=>drop schema public cascade;
```

I waited for about 10 minutes and I got no response back.  So I quit the terminal (In retrospect probably a bad decision).  Now, when I try and access my models:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Tool
>>> Tool.objects.all()
```

I get no response back.  When I try to log into the app on heroku I get a timeout error.  When I run the app locally I get `waiting for 127.0.0.1` which continues onto infinity with out a response.

I'm stumped and not sure what's happening.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: check `pg_locks`. (Sorry for short comment, just signing off now).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to wipe the database and get responses back with this [unaccepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735675/heroku-app-with-django-and-postgres-crashing-unexpectdly?rq=1)

I wish I would have found this earlier when I was searching stack and the heroku-postgres docs.